# What does a Google Maps API call look like to get collection of alternate routes

Tags: google-maps

I manually created a URL to create a route between two addresses on Google Maps

https://maps.google.ca?saddr=16+st.+laurent+PL,+halifax,+NS,+CA&daddr=39+red+fern,+halifax,+NS,+CA

And the resulting web page returned gives a primary route and two alternate routes you can choose in the left drop down navigation.

My question is how can I call the Google API to get the collection of routes and then how can I build a URL to call a specific route?

I notice after I hit enter on my original URL it refreshes the page with a new URL and it has a data parameter with some values and that those values change if I choose alternate routes.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps JavaScript API's `DirectionsRequest` object has a property `provideRouteAlternatives` which you can set to `true`.
The returned `DirectionsResponse` object will have a `routes` array which contains the main route *and* the alternates.

Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to take that API result and create a URL.  You might be able to compare a URL that you have to an API result and see if there are similarities that you can exploit.

---

For the Google Maps **Web Service** API, here is a quote from the documentation:

> Generally, only one entry in the `routes` array is returned for directions lookups, though the Directions service may return several routes if you pass `alternatives=true`.

However, the same note applies here - I have not seen a way offhand to turn this data into a URL.

Comment: Thanks Moshe.I should have noted that I am looking to do this from within C#.Net so can't use the javascript framework.  I need to make direct HTTPS calls with query string parameters. I don't recall seeing any parameter for provideRoutAlternatives in the docs about direct HTTPS calls but I will go back and double check.

Comment: @user461051 I have updated the answer with how to get alternative routes using a query string parameter.

Comment: Thanks Moshe. The URL I give in my example actually does return alternate routes when I look at the resulting page. so I got to thinking that maybe it has assumes alternatives=true as default value. however, if I set alternatives=false it still gives aleternate routes so doesn't sound like that is a query parameter for how I am calling the api.

Comment: What is interesting is if I add another query string on my query for output, I get different outputs but not exactly what I would expect. If I do &output=xml, it still seems to give an html page but it is a slightly different page than the initial one in that it lists out the directions in the left pane for the default direction. if I use &output=json it sends back a .txt file. It appears it is json but the first command in the file is a "while(1);" which seems odd but I am no json guru so maybe that makes sense.

Comment: @user461051 can you post a sample URL that you are using? (for privacy, just choose two random commercial addresses or landmarks for the route.)

Comment: Sure.  https://maps.google.ca?saddr=12+main+street,+halifax,+NS,+CA&daddr=20+main+street+trurro+NS+CA    https://maps.google.ca?saddr=12+main+street,+halifax,+NS,+CA&daddr=20+main+street+trurro+NS+CA&output=xml    https://maps.google.ca?saddr=12+main+street,+halifax,+NS,+CA&daddr=20+main+street+trurro+NS+CA&output=json